# CORS Chrome Extension with manifest version 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to use CORS when writing a google chrome extension?

I saw this, 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

And I tried inserting this into the manifest,
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://twitter.com/; object-src 'self'",

but an ajax requestion fails with 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://twitter.com/. Origin chrome-extension://olimhkjfpndfhdopbneamnekfalckinc is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Content Security Policy and Cross-Origin Resource Sharing are totally different. The CSP is a way for the client to block things that would otherwise be allowed by the same-origin policy, like loading `<script>`s. CORS is a way for the server to allows things that would otherwsie be blocked (i.e., cross-domain Ajax).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To enable [cross-origin Ajax](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) from your extension to Twitter, you simply need to list Twitter as a host permission in your manifest:

```
...
"permissions": [
    "*://*.twitter.com/*"
],
...
```

Comment: in chrome 76 my permission is fine.But in chrome 77 that permission have not allowing the CORS

Comment: not working anymore in 2022

Comment: @ShivSingh This is still a valid match pattern to allow fetching from a particular host; however, I think modern extensions are only allowed to make cross-origin requests from background pages. If you're attempting to do a cross-origin request from within a content script, it will be blocked by Chrome regardless of permissions. (You would need to have the fetch happen in the background page and have content script communicate with the background page via extension message passing.) Also Manifest v3 only allows `fetch`, not `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: yes working with background

Comment: @apsillers update for v3 manifest `"host_permissions": ["https://*/"],`

Comment: @apsillers do you know In what cases such host permission would be required to fetch from a particular host in MV3 from the background (service worker)? I'm doing some tests and it seems that fetch works just fine without any host permissions.

Answer (score 40):

**Update** 2023-11-18: This all applies to `"manifest_version": 2` and even though Google has been threatening for a while to reject it, I'm still using it. Mainly because v3 doesn't have `.getPackageDirectoryEntry()` which means I can't listen to my files and have hot reload. So I'm hoping they'll add that back in (or something similar) before I have to switch.

### Explanation

As of Chrome 73, cross site requests are blocked.
(Even if you have the hosts in your permissions property.)
Some sites seem to get through unblocked but I'm sure eventually most won't.

You have to make the request in a **background page...**

---

### Setup

Add a section to your `manifest.json` to point to the background page.
If you're using manifest v3, you'll need a `service_worker` property here intead of `scripts`.

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["bg_page.js"],
  "persistent": false
}
```

Create the background page: `bg_page.js`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(url, sender, onSuccess) {
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(responseText => onSuccess(responseText))
        
        return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
    }
);
```

Then use it in `main.js`

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage( //goes to bg_page.js
      url,
      data => dataProcessFunction(data) //your callback
);
```

---

### Additional Tips

If you do anything like `console.log()` from the bg page, click the "inspect views background page" link in your extension's square in chrome's extensions manager and you'll get a separate dev tools window for everything that happens with your background page.

If you want to see the docs for yourself:

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/background_pages/
- https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches/#2-avoid-cross-origin-fetches-in-content-scripts

Comment: does this also works with making requests under default_popup?

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer - Not sure, never messed with browserActions. You could test by creating a button in your popup.html that calls that same function in your background page. Or if you haven't setup your background page yet, that button could just call a function in your background page that simply does a console log. (Just make sure to check for it under "inspect views background page.")

Comment: I had to combine this answer with the adding the origin as a permission (as suggested in the accepted answer) - both together did the trick.

Comment: But ain't there a need to define permission for cross-site request URLs in manifest? Something like `"permissions": ["https://www.someurl.com/*", ...]`. I've posted a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67106588/cross-site-requests-from-background-script-works-even-if-not-allowed-in-manifest

Comment: @Incredible - I no longer need the permissions section in my manifest file for local extensions (background pages and the process I described seems to be good enough) but you may need to do both as Bert H said above.

Comment: @Brad Quite the opposite. It works for me even without the permission and I wonder why. Perhaps because I'm using `"content_scripts": [{ "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],...`

Comment: I see. That `content_scripts...` section determines which sites your extension will run on when you load that url in the browser. An extension that makes a call to a different site from what the browser is currently pointed to is where the permissions section / background page comes in. As a guess (I'm certainly no CORS expert), I wonder if a permissions section / background page is needed when the outside site you're calling doesn't allow cross origin requests. If you're connecting to your own site, you probably don't have that restricted so you may not need either to make that call.

Comment: As another wild guess, Google may have rejected your manifest with the permissions section because some automated approval process connected to your permission url, saw that it wasn't restricted and judged your permission "excessive"? As for why Bert H needed both, I'm not sure. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: "The "background.scripts" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead."

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE FOR MANIFEST V3**

---

I figured out a way to do this. But be extremely careful with your url filtering and other safeguards.

As of Manifest v3 you can set rules for modifying incoming and outgoing calls. Include the name of the site you are requesting in a new section of the manifest called `"host_permissions"`. You can see how to implement rules in the manifest here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#manifest

There is a rule action called `"allowAllRequests"` using this rule allows you to make cross-origin-requests, bypassing preflight checks. You can read more about the rules here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#type-RuleActionType

To use this rule you will need to include the `"resourceTypes"` key in `"condition"` and a value of `"main_frame"` or `"sub_frame"`

Also make sure to completely uninstall your extension and reinstall it for these changes to take effect.

---

Example manifest from google:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...

  "declarative_net_request" : {
    "rule_resources" : [{
      "id": "ruleset_1",
      "enabled": true,
      "path": "rules_1.json"
    }, {
      "id": "ruleset_2",
      "enabled": false,
      "path": "rules_2.json"
    }]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "*://example.com/*"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "http://www.blogger.com/",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  ...
}
```

Example Rule.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "priority": 1,
        "action": { "type": "allowAllRequests" },
        "condition": {
            "urlFilter": "again make sure you are very specific with this.",
            "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

for V3 you just need to add

```
"host_permissions": ["https://*/"]
```

And you are suposed to REMOVE your extension - not reload. Then add again and you're good to go. =)

Answer (score 0):

For Manifest V3 this worked for me.

```
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://api.jdoodle.com/v1/execute",
    "*://*/*"
  ],
```