# Chrome extension cross origin with laravel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, laravel-5, cors

I'm creating a chrome extension to communicate with my laravel app.

I've configured [laravel cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) on my project.

I added this line on my app.php file :

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

I added cors middleware to my route group :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/', 'middleware' => ['cors']], function () {
    // routes ...
});
```

In my chrome extension I call my route with $http :

```
$http({
   url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/bookmarks',
   method: 'GET'
}).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
})
```

In chrome debugger I've following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/bookmarks. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.   Origin 
'chrome-extension://ndgoclipaencbojjmcfkohfekdbhdnjf' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried many solution found on github or stackoverflow :

Add this on index.php `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Change defaults header config with angular :

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

Change $execpt property on VerifyCsrfToken class :

```
protected $except = [
    'auth/*', 'api/*'
];
```

I have missed something in my config ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT

I've also added this to manifest.json file :

```
"permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "http://localhost:8000/*"
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CORS Chrome Extension with manifest version 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2)

Comment: Did you reload your extension after adding the localhost permission to your manifest? You can't get the error you quote if the permission is set.

Comment: Thanks sanchez. I've reloaded my extension some times and now it works.

Comment: Then you can accept the close as duplicate vote, as the original problem was the missing `permissions`