# How to bypass CORS for Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors

I'm reading in a bunch of images and then loading them into coresponding canvases. However i sometimes get this error:

```
SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 
The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Is there a way to "insist" on reading the data even though its been tainted? Or can i bypass this part of the CORS entirely since I'm developing an extension and not a webpage?

Comment: From what I remember this is a security concern that you can't circumvent.

Comment: The only solution is to add `permissions` to your manifest. These can be partially-regexed, for example: `"permissions": [ "*://*.twitter.com/*" ],`. Thankfully, there is no way for an extension to completely bypass Chrome's own CORS policy.

Comment: @BenM That's to bad... (in this case at least)

Comment: how about using your own server with cors to fetch the needed data. then in the extension you wont need to add permissions.

Comment: To bypass Chrome CORS - send the request from your extn.background page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS Chrome Extension with manifest version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2)