# Chrome Extension *Background* Script access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, cors

I have a Chrome Extension published which luckily has a decently sized user base (thousands of users).

The background page connects to my server to verify their subscription.

For ~95% of users this works as intended, and on every machine I have tested, it works as intended.

According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr, "a script executing in an extension's background page or foreground tab can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as the extension requests cross-origin permissions."  My manifest.json specifies my server domain in the permissions, and again, this is seemingly working for the vast majority of users with no issue.

Occasionally I get support requests from users who are being blocked and ultimately provide a screenshot of the background page dev console showing the error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.mydomainname.com/check_subscription.php?guid=example-example-example-example' from origin 'chrome-extension://abcexampleexampleexample' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

What, if anything, could cause some users computers to have this issue and not others?  I'm interested in anything that could cause this, whether it's something I can fix in my code, or something that users can fix on their computer, or any other solutions.

Comment: I guess it is firewall or something. Do you add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to the response to check_subscription?

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I tried adding that header but it didn't change anything for the affected customers, oddly.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to bypass cors policy with CORS proxy,
Just prefix your URL with **'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'**

***For example***, if you are requesting at:
**https://www.mydomainname.com/check_subscription.php?** , then

you have to request at :
**'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.mydomainname.com/check_subscription.php?'**

This URL is a proxy for CORS policy and it will work like magic.

Comment: Interesting, but ultimately I don't think this can help since the requested URL is under my control and already has permissive CORS headers.

Answer (score 1):

This can help you

> Explanation
> As of Chrome 73, cross site requests are blocked. (Even if you have the hosts in your permissions property.) Some sites seem to get through unblocked but I'm sure eventually most won't.
>
> You have to make the request in a background page...
>
> Setup Add a section to your manifest.json to point to the background
> page.
>
> "background": {   "scripts": ["bg_page.js"],   "persistent": false }
> Create the background page: bg_page.js
>
> chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
> function(url, sender, onSuccess) {
> fetch(url)
> .then(response => response.text())
> .then(responseText => onSuccess(responseText))
>
> ```
>     return true;  // Will respond asynchronously.
> } ); Then use it in main.js
> ```
>
> chrome.runtime.sendMessage( //goes to bg_page.js
> url,
> data => dataProcessFunction(data) );  Additional Tips If you do anything like console.log() from the bg page, click the "inspect views
> background page" link in your extension's square in chrome's
> extensions manager and you'll get a separate dev tools window for
> everything that happens with your background page.
>
> If you want to see the docs for yourself, check out step 2 of the
> Recommended Developer Actions section here:
> https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches#TOC-2.-Avoid-Cross-Origin-Fetches-in-Content-Scripts

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2)

Comment: The question is specifically about why it already (sporadically) does not work in the background page, not about how to create a background page.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

to your script? The '*' character is a wild card that allows access a request to come from any domain.

For a more in-depth approach, have you considered using a pre-flight request? Some info via [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

> Unlike “simple requests” (discussed above), for "preflighted" requests
> the browser first sends an HTTP request using the OPTIONS method to
> the resource on the other origin, in order to determine if the actual
> request is safe to send. Cross-site requests are preflighted like this
> since they may have implications to user data.

Lastly, and just throwing this out there since you are a Chrome extension developer, [CNET offers a good article detailing the woes of the upcoming Manifest v3 in mid-January 2021.](https://www.cnet.com/news/here-comes-the-google-chrome-change-that-worries-ad-blocker-creators/) This might be a good resource to check out so you can see if you'll have any issues with your user base come the new year.

Comment: Hi.  Yes.  That's on the server, but for some reason some people are getting blocked anyway.