# Cross-site requests from background script works even if not allowed in manifest V2?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, cors, cross-domain

This is in my manifest.js:

```
  {
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "description": "__MSG_appDesc__",
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "default_locale": "en",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "icons": { 
      "16": "assets/img/icon16.png",
      "48": "assets/img/icon48.png",
      "128": "assets/img/icon128.png" 
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["consts.js", "api.js", "background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [
          "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js": ["consts.js", "selectors.js", "scanner.js", "content.js"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "__MSG_appName__"
    }
  }
```

In background script I'm making fetch requests to my own REST API running on my own domain: https://www.axelproductions86.com/api/provision, for example:

```
fetch(API.URL_API + '/feedback', {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  headers: { "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" }
})
```

In [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/xhr/) I read:

> a script executing in an extension's background page or foreground tab can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as the extension requests cross-origin permissions.

and that I should have in the manifest:

```
"permissions": ["https://www.axelproductions86.com/*", ...],
```

if I want to use the cross-site requests. But I don't have it there and it still works. Originally there was something similar in the manifest, but Google rejected my upload at first and told me to remove the excessive permission. Is there an explanation why it works even without an url permission?

Comment: I guess you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing. Otherwise it's a bug.

Comment: Oh I did, I tried it also from chrome web store directly in linux and windows.