# use fetch function will go wrong in my chrome extension ,it will not send cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I want to call **fetch** function to get some data from the server in my background.js。
like this：

```
    fetch("https://api.bilibili.com/x/space/acc/info?mid=402655790&jsonp=jsonp")
    .then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
    })
```

but the console print
[error description photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdZnL.png)

I found some method to solve this problem。
use   `mode:"no-cors"`

Finally, I successfully sent a request,but there was no response.

[request success,status code ==200 photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7vVm.png)

[no data response photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVmmK.png)

Besides, I found there is no cookie’s in my  request header

[no cookies in request header photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmrnV.png)

How can I send a request successfully，and get the correct data from the server?

Comment: i try to insert cookies like this
```
fetch("xxx",{
  method:"GET",
  mode:"no-cors",
  headers:{
  cookie:"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
})
```

but it does not work, it has not cookies in my request message

Comment: for a start - `mode:"no-cors"` guarantees you wont' be able to access the result - as for cookies, `fetch` only sends cookies if you ask it it - it's [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) how to send cookies cross origin - since the issue is CORS, then you won't be able to fetch from that API from the browser - you'll need to *proxy* the request through your own server

Comment: also adding `jsonp` won't make the API send jsonp (as you've seen) - besides, JSONP needs to be handled very differently to AJAX

Comment: Shouldn't this be a case of adding `credentials: 'include'` to the request setup?

Answer (score 1):

I found that there was an answer similar to my question,
[CORS Chrome Extension with manifest version 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2)。
this problem is caused by CORS。
it can be solved by adding permissions to the manifest.json
like this:

```
    "permissions": [
      "https://*/"
    ],
```