# I am trying to build a chrome extension that relies on sending an http request to a website and am confused

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome-extension, project

As the title says I am working on a chrome extension that part of its functionality is to send a http request to a website, get a response, and parse the data it receives.
My problem is that trying to send the request using JS results in a cors error, while trying to do it locally in pycharm using python works without a problem.
My question is why does python requests go through while JS fetch does not, and is there a way to actually make the chrome extension work?
To be clear the website I am sending the request requires a user-agent header that causes the cors error.

Comment: Your Python code is a standalone request.  Your Javascript request is embedded as part of a web page that came from another location.  You might show us your JS code to see if you're doing the headers properly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357485/cors-chrome-extension-with-manifest-version-2

Comment: JavaScript code is subject to CORS because it's being run from within a browser, and browsers enforce CORS.  Your Python code works because it's sending a raw HTTP request to the website (basically acting as the browser) so it doesn't care about CORS because it's not running in the context of a website. Extensions are an exception to this rule, but you do need to add a permission to your extension that says it can access the website you're trying to access. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358874/10601203

Comment: @jesse Even after adding permissions I am still getting an error saying "Refused to set unsafe header "user-agent". Any way to work around it? without this header the request doesnt get all the data I need

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue. Please don't ask a different question in the comments. There aren't enough details here to answer that. It sounds like it could be related to your browser version as that header used to be restricted but is not any more.

Comment: Actually scratch that. It looks like you can set the user agent of the browser itself, but you can't set the user agent of an `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.